# setBackgroundMessageHandler: How to invoke when app is in quit state on iOS

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I am using the `react-native-firebase` library.

On iOS, I am able to receive notifications in the foreground, background and also when the app is in quit state. Handlers work in every scenario too, except for one.

My only problem is: `setBackgroundMessageHandler` is not being invoked when the app is in quit state, even though I am receiving the notification. I also tried to send data-only messages but the result was the same.

I am even able to invoke the app in a headless state using `content-available: 1` in the message's apns section.

But still the `setBackgroundMessageHandler` is not getting invoked. This is my `index.js` page:

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('HEADLESS BACKGROUND: ' + ' | ' + JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
});

function HeadlessCheck({ isHeadless }) {
  if (isHeadless) {
    console.log("Headless");
    // App has been launched in the background by iOS, ignore
    return null;
  }

  return <App />;
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => HeadlessCheck);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning `null` from in case of a headless invocation, return a simple component that contains nothing and renders nothing.

**Index.js**

```js
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
  console.log('HEADLESS BACKGROUND: ' + JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
});

function HeadlessCheck({ isHeadless }) {
  if (isHeadless) {
    console.log('Headless');
    return <AppFake />;
    /* Notice this component, it is not the App Component but a different one*/
  }

  return <App />;
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => HeadlessCheck);
```

The AppFake component simply contains this:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';

const AppFake = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default AppFake;
```

I did have to hide the `SplashScreen`. This was essential in my case.

Here is the payload that I send from the server:

```js
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

const message = {
  notification: {
    title: title,
    body: body,
  },
  data: { campaignId: campaignId, title: title, body: body },
  token: registrationId,
  android: {
    priority: 'high',
    notification: {
      title: title,
      body: body,
      sound: 'default',
    },
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        sound: 'default',
        'content-available': 1,
      },
    },
    headers: {
      'apns-priority': '5',
    },
  },
};

let response = admin
  .messaging()
  .send(message)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Now the `setBackgroundMessageHandler` is going to be invoked on every new message even when the app is in the quit state on iOS.

Comment: Hi @kartikey i was trying to implement the above for my react native application for iOS. I'm able to receive the push notification, but not able to trigger the backgroundhandler callback. Do i need to add anything from the ios native code in AppDelegate for the headless invocation. I'm getting crash as Can't find variable React in index.js file. I'm using the exact solution as above. Kindly Help. Thanks

Comment: Are the `imports` correct?? See, when you get this error saying `Can't find variable React..` it's basically because you have not imported it at the top. Just add `import React from "react"`. Again, this is just my assumption as far as the error is concerned. And yes, follow the installation instructions for `react-native-firebase`. Ping me if the problem still persists.

Comment: My bad i have not imported the React from 'react'. Thanks for pointing it out @Kartikey. I have one question regarding the setBackgroundMessageHandler method. When we kill the app and recieved notification how do get to know that this method is getting called. Debugging logs won't work when i kill the app for Javascript lib?, So how do make sure this method is called.? Do i need check this scenario in Release Build?

Comment: Thanks a ton, this does the trick in iOS. Any idea on how can I get this event executed on Android in quit state?